# password_hash, password_verify, MySQL misunderstanding?

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

I can't seem to get this test to display the hashed password from the database. It displays the password from the form just fine. Trying to do this test to figure out why I can't get it to verify the password from the form compared to the password stored in the database. I read something about escaping the $ signs that are within the hash but I'm not sure on how to do that with the code I'm working with. Either way, something isn't right. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
require('../connect.php');
$username = $_POST['username-sign-in'];
$password = $_POST['password-sign-in'];
$hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);
if (empty($username)) {
    echo 'Please enter your username.';
    exit();
}
if (empty($password)) {
    echo 'Please enter your password.';
    exit();
}
if (isset($username, $password)) {
    $getuser = $connection->prepare('SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?');
    $getuser->bind_param('ss', $username, $hashedpassword);
    $getuser->execute();
    $userdata = $getuser->get_result();
    $row = $userdata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo 'Password from form: ' . $hashedpassword . '<br />';
    echo 'Password from DB: ' . $row['password'] . '<br />';
    if (password_verify($row['password'], $hashedpassword)) {
        echo 'Success.';
        exit();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Fail.';
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Please enter your username and password.';
    $connection->close();
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You cannot query against the user supplied password that's the entire idea of using hashes. Drop the `AND password = ?` The hash will be different every time you hash the password

Comment: See the usage section https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: @JakeGould Did you miss the part where I state the hashed password will be different every time? I.e. the stored hash will always be different if you run the hashing again

Comment: What sort of system are you running with all the text echo and then deaths? Is it a site or some kind of API?

Comment: It's all AJAX on the front-end. The problem lies within the server-side code for sure. I've check what data is being POST-ed with Firebug and it's all correct.

Comment: I may have figured out my problem...password_hash by default or when set to PASSWORD_BCRYPT should produce a 60 character hash, correct? Mine is only showing 32 chars in the database column. So I assume that my strlen is somehow messing things up? The db column for password is varchar 255.

Comment: Actually, it was set to 32...I believe I've found my problem lmao. Thanks for all of your help! I'll report back if the problem still isn't fixed.

Answer (score 24):

You can't hash the input and then query against that in the database, as the hash will use a different random salt each time.  So you could hash the same password a thousand times and get 1000 different results.

You need to simply just query the DB for the record related to the username, then compare the password hash returned from the DB with the input password using `password_verify()`.

Also, when initially writing the hash to the DB on password creation (using `password_hash()`) there is no need to escape the hash.  `password_hash()` is not used at all in the password verification process.

Comment: I was wondering how to do a `WHERE user = ? and password = {what the hell to put there}` and check if I got 1 result, but I actually did not think about that `WHERE user = ?` + retrieve hashed pass + `password_verify()` ! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

From a quick glance at the functions it seems that you may have got the test the wrong way round.

You should store the hashed version of the password in the db and then compare that with the password provided through the $_POST.. then the rest would go like..

```
$getuser = $connection->prepare('SELECT `password` 
                                        FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?');
$getuser->bind_param('s', $username);
$getuser->execute();
$userdata = $getuser->get_result();
$row = $userdata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo 'Password from form: ' . $hashedpassword . '<br />';
echo 'Password from DB: ' . $row['password'] . '<br />';
if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
    // $password being $_POST['password-sign-in']
    // $row['password'] being the hashed password saved in the database
    echo 'Success.';
    exit();
} else {
    echo 'Fail.';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I live to be ignored.

Comment: Nono, I took your advice! Haha, I ignore no one! I've posted the updated code within a new answer.

Comment: You should put your update in your original question rather than an answer as it makes for a confusing read.

Comment: Is the password stored in the database stored using the `password_hash()` function?

Comment: Yes, it's stored into the database using the password_hash() function.

Comment: Add the whole process to the question. Hashing, setting, getting, checking, etc.

Comment: I've added the code from signup.php, hopefully it helps you all help me! Haha, much appreciated btw!

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted to change the single quotes like `'`:

```
$getuser = $connection->prepare('SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?');
$getuser->bind_param('ss', $username, $hashedpassword);
```

To double quotes like `"`

```
$getuser = $connection->prepare("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
$getuser->bind_param("ss", $username, $hashedpassword);
```

Also, why are you matching against `password`? Perhaps this would work for your test case:

```
$getuser = $connection->prepare("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
$getuser->bind_param("s", $username);
```

**EDIT** Also, you are essentially double-hashing the password when you do your check:

```
if (password_verify($row['password'], $hashedpassword)) {
```

Just do this instead:

```
if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
```

The issue is that [`password_verify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) has the syntax of:

```
boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
```

You need to send the plain/non-hashed password in the first param & then place the hashed value in the second param. Try it out.

Comment: What good would changing the single quotes to double quotes possibly do?

Comment: Ideas and guesses belong in the comments section. However this idea doesn't make much sense. You are right about the dropping of the password in the query though

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked! I took the AND password = ? out, now it's returning the string from the database. But it's still giving me the "Fail." message so I guess I'm still confused on what I'm doing wrong within the password_verify().

Answer (score -1):

the problem is usually when you hash user input from a form it is hashed as if it has double quotes. that's why you see the hash starting with $2y$10...... I think you should try to solve it from this point. if you are giving an answer also consider  this