# admin password in config.php from database

Tags: php, database

I am new to php I have a question. I've one website for which admin password is defined in config.php please see below

```
?>
<?
// admin constants
define("ADMIN_LOGIN","admin");      // username of administrator to login
define("ADMIN_PASSWORD","123456");      // password of administrator to login

// admin e-mail
define("ADMIN_NAME","Admin");       // username of administrator to login
define("SITE_NAME","XXX");
define("SUPPORT_EMAIL","xxx@yahoo.com");
define("MAIL_TO_CUSTOMER_NAME","DoNotreply@xxx.com");
define("MAIL_TO_CUSTOMER","DoNotreply@xxx.com");    // email of website admin
define("ADMIN_EMAIL","info@xxxs.com");  // email of website admin
define("DOMAIN","");
```

I want to get admin password from database so I should have option to change password through front end.

Comment: This is a good way to store and access DB informations but I would recommend to create a specific user with restricted rights to access your database for security reasons.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I mean all the time i've to go to config.php and update password periodically. Instead i want to link this to database field so i can update from front end.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to save the password at all. You save the username and a hashed version of the password in the database. When someone wants to log in you hash the password they enter and compare the two hashes.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070192/1501491) probably does exactly what you want to do:

Please check out the official PHP documentation on [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).